# What is the design pattern name of onboarding popups jumping step by step (image)

Tags: design-patterns, onboarding, tutorial

we would like to implement functionality like below, but I cannot find out name of this ux pattern.

Those screen is from GSuite admin but you can find it in many applications. It jumps step by step introducing and focusing around major changes.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commonly called Guided tour tooltip. Also called Product tour tooltip, Onboarding tooltip and so on. It's essentially a tooltip!

Comment: Guided Tour is often the name of the larger tool. The tooltip is the specific element used to call out a specific element or step.